# Joining 2 tables with a timestamp of YEAR for the first item purchased by customer

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, postgresql-12

I have 2 tables "items" and "customers".

In both tables, "customer_id" is present and a single customer can have more than 1 item. In the "items" table there is also a timestamp field called "date_created" when an item was purchased.

I want to construct a query that can return each customer_id and item_id associated with the first item each customer bought in a specific year, let's say 2020.

My approach was

```
SELECT customer_id, items
INNER JOIN items ON items.customer_id=customers.customer_id
```

and then try to use the EXTRACT function to take care of the first item each customer bought in 2020 but I can't seem to extract the first item only for the specific year. I would really appreciate some help.
I am using PostgreSQL. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (customer_id) i.*
from items i
where date_created >= date '2020-01-01' and
      date_created < date '2021-01-01'
order by customer_id, date_created;
```

First, note the use of direct date comparisons.  This makes it easier for the optimizer to choose the best execution plan.

`distinct on` is a handy Postgres extension that returns the first row encountered for the keys in parentheses, which must be the first keys in the `order by`.  "First" is based on the subsequent `order by` keys.